# запуск jar из командной строки

Tags: java

Как запустить приложение java. jar файл из командной строки. Оно уже есть, его нужно запустить. не Исходный файл скомпилировать и запустить (javac и java), а запустить готовый файл (приложение) jar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для запуска в консоли пропишите:
`java -jar /home/user/jar_name.jar` - для Linux
`java -jar C:\Users\user\jar_name.jar` - для Windows